# pix4d vertical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, pix4d, vertical

I've been given Ground control points for job and the vertical co-ordinates are in AHD (Australian Height Datum). Does anyone out there have any idea how to transform vertical heights in AHD to Pix4d accepted vertical coordinate system?

e.g. MSL emg88 or 94 or08.

Also I have access to ArcGIS, QGIS etc for transformation etc..